# How can i use rigidbody2d.velocity to follow an object in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need the Player to follow the moving Target and stop exactly when it reaches the Target.
The Player has to reach the Target almost instantaneously in every frame, so i need a high speed way to do it.

I couldn't use Transform.translate because there's a lot of physics implementations in my game and using Transform.translate or movetowards made the physics buggy.

Is there any physics based way to follow the target? velocity, AddForce, anything? For a 2D game. 
Any leads would be greatly appreciated! Thank You!

Comment: think you might be looking for [rigidbody.position](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-position.html)

Comment: If you have a ton of physics going on and don't want to deal with it in code, you can use a physics joint to attach the player to the target.   Just to be sure though, your other tries were in FixedUpdate not Update, right?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a `Rigidbody2D` you want to follow another object, the [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html)  is the proper way to move it.

Do the following:

**1**.Disable gravity by setting the "Gravity Scale" to 0.

**2**.Change the BodyType to Kinematic.

**3**.You can now move the `Rigidbody` object to follow another GameObject with the [`Rigidbody2D.MovePosition`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody2D.MovePosition.html) function. See code below. This should be done in the `FixedUpdate` function and with `Time.fixedDeltaTime` instead of `Time.deltatime`.

Finally, if you still get jerky movement, change *Interpolate* option from *None* to   *Interpolate* or *Extrapolate*. I would also suggest reducing the speed variable below.

```
//Object to follow
public Transform target;
//Rigidbody to move
public Rigidbody2D rb2d;
public float speed = 7.0f;
//Distance to start moving
public float minDistance = 0.09f;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    //Find direction
    Vector3 dir = (target.transform.position - rb2d.transform.position).normalized;
    //Check if we need to follow object then do so 
    if (Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, rb2d.transform.position) > minDistance)
    {
        rb2d.MovePosition(rb2d.transform.position + dir * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's too bad the OP didn't mark this as the answer - this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the velocity directly is always a bad practice and should be avoided. Instead always work with AddForce.
I would calculate the distance between the target and the body and add a force based on that distance.

```
var dif = target.transform.pos - body.transform.pos;
bodyRigid.AddForce(dif * multiplier * Time.deltatime);
```

The only problem that comes with that solution might be the fact that the body 'shakes' around the target once its to close.
You could avoid this by checking if the body is close to target and then freezing it.

```
var dif = target.transform.pos - body.transform.pos;
if(dif.magnitude > 1) {
    bodyRigid.AddForce(dif * multiplier * Time.deltatime);
} else {
    bodyRigid.velocity = Vector2.zero;
}
```

Although I said that setting the velocity directly is a bad habit, using it to just freeze the body should be fine. I have no idea whether that might break your other physics that you use in your game, duo the fact that that just strait up freezes your object.
You can also change the distance (1 in the if statement) that it needs in order to freeze, just play around with it a bit and find a value that fits the game